# why java class WeakReference does not override hashcode and equals

Tags: java, weak-references

I was expecting the WeakReference class to override hashCode and equals methods like this

```
class WeakReference<T>{
  T ref;

  int hashCode(){
    return ref.hashCode();
  }

  boolean equals(Object o){
    return ref.equals(o);
  }
}
```

So that I could use We WeakReference directly as key in hashmaps like

```
Person p1 = new Person("p1");
WeakReference<Person> wr = new WeakReference<Person>(p1);

map.put(wr, "some value object");
```

But when I tested I found out that hashCode and equals are not overridden

```
Person p1 = new Person("p1");
WeakReference<Person> wr = new WeakReference<Person>(p1);
WeakReference<Person> wr2 = new WeakReference<Person>(p1);

System.out.println(wr.hashCode()); // prints x
System.out.println(wr2.hashCode()); // prints y

System.out.println(wr.equals(wr2)); // prints false
```

Any specific reasons reasons that hashCode and equals are not overridden in WeakReference class?

Comment: Because there is no need, given that [`WeakHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) will do what you want.

Comment: If `WeakReference` had overridden `equals` and `hashCode` it would be a very bad idea to use them as `HashMap` keys. This is because the `hashCode` of the `WeakReference` would almost certainly change when the object held is taken away. You should never cause a `HashMap` key to change after putting it in because it's then no longer possible to find it.

Comment: So…every collected key is equal to any other collected key? That’s a *really* bad idea…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important aspect of any key on a Map (or element of a Set) is that it must be immutable (or at least not change) once it has been added to the collection. Changing a key has undefined behaviour which is highly unlikely to work.

A WeakReference can change at any time due to a GC being performed i.e. in ways you have no control over, which makes the equals/hashCode inappropriate for general collections which use these.

> I was trying to make MyWeakConcurrentHashMap

A simple way of doing this is to have an array of WeakHashMaps. e.g. 32 partitions . Use the hashCode() to determine which WeakHashMap to use.  This way you can have a thread accessing each of the individual WeakHashMap at once (best case)

As you have more concurrency you can increase the number of partitions.

Comment: That's not a problem.  The weak reference could compute the hashcode in its constructor, and cache it, so it would never change.

Comment: @MikeNakis any how would it cache the information for equals?

Comment: Actually I was trying to make MyWeakConcurrentHashMap by wrapping ConcurrentHashMap and wrapping/unwrapping map key inside weak reference. Consumers need not be aware of this. It would have worked fine if weakrefeerence had implemented hashCode and equals as pr my expectations.

Comment: @Mangoose though that's not possible to do as a WeakReference can change at any time, so you need to handle such a key differently.

Comment: @PeterLawrey  and mike Thanks for this wonderful discussion and making the point clear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `WeakHashMap` uses `Entry` which extends `WeakReference`
and overrides both `hashCode` and `equals`,
 you can take a look of their implementation.

```
  /**
     * The entries in this hash table extend WeakReference, using its main ref
     * field as the key.
     */
    private static class Entry<K,V> extends WeakReference<Object> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
        V value;
        final int hash;
        Entry<K,V> next;

        /**
         * Creates new entry.
         */
        Entry(Object key, V value,
              ReferenceQueue<Object> queue,
              int hash, Entry<K,V> next) {
            super(key, queue);
            this.value = value;
            this.hash  = hash;
            this.next  = next;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public K getKey() {
            return (K) WeakHashMap.unmaskNull(get());
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public V setValue(V newValue) {
            V oldValue = value;
            value = newValue;
            return oldValue;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))
                return false;
            Map.Entry<?,?> e = (Map.Entry<?,?>)o;
            K k1 = getKey();
            Object k2 = e.getKey();
            if (k1 == k2 || (k1 != null && k1.equals(k2))) {
                V v1 = getValue();
                Object v2 = e.getValue();
                if (v1 == v2 || (v1 != null && v1.equals(v2)))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            K k = getKey();
            V v = getValue();
            return Objects.hashCode(k) ^ Objects.hashCode(v);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return getKey() + "=" + getValue();
        }
    }
```